# More than one condition in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file containing lines in the following format:

```
<firstname> <lastname> <day_of_birth> <month_of_birth> <year_of_birth>
```

I need to display the users who celebrate their birthday at the current date.

I managed to write the script but only by checking if the day == the current day.

How can I write the line with awk where I check if $3 == day, also checking if $4 == month and $5 == year? Thank you

```
# get current date: day, month, year
day="$(date +'%d')"
month="$(date +'%m')"
year="$(date +'%Y')"

birthdays=$(awk "\$3~/$day/ {print \$1, \$2;}" users.lst)
echo $birthdays
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current date from *within* `awk` as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    "date +%d" | getline day
    "date +%m" | getline month
    "date +%Y" | getline year        
}
$3==day && $4==month && $5==year {
   print $1,$2
}' users.lst
```

Comment: If you're considering using getline, make sure you ready and fully understand all of the caveats described at http://awk.info/?tip/getline. Personally, I wouldn't use getline for this but YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the comment. At http://awk.info/?tip/getline it says `getline is an appropriate solution for reading from a pipe`. However, I wonder, do you see any problems here? For instance, should the pipes be closed before accessing the variables `day`, `month` and `year`. Or can we rely on that they have a well defined value even if the pipe is not closed?

Comment: getline is an appropriate solution for reading for a pipe BUT in this case there's no reason to be reading from a pipe unlike, say, when you're reading data from a file using awk and find it useful to call some shell command to operate on that data and then use getline to read the result and then continue processing in awk. Yes the pipes should always be closed as soon as you're done with each of them (e.g. `cmd="date +%d"; cmd | getline day; close(cmd)`), I'm not sure what the consequences are of not doing so in this case - I just do it so I don't need to read up on why.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just shell variables in awk like this. It might create many problems. You need to pass shell variables to awk using `-v awk_var=$shell_var` option.

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v d=$day -v m=$month -v y=$year '$3==d && $4==m && $5==y {print $1, $2}' users.lst
```

However please note the [**GNU awk has built-in date/time functions**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) and you can just avoid calling date command 3 times before awk like this:

```
awk '$3==strftime("%d") && $4==strftime("%m") && $5==strftime("%Y")
     {print $1, $2}' users.lst
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post any sample input so it's a guess, but this is probably what you want:

```
awk -v date=$(date "+%d/%m/%Y") '$3"/"$4"/"$5 == date {print $1, $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:

```
awk '$3=="'$(date +%d)'"&&$4=="'$(date +%m)'"&&$5=="'$(date +%Y)'"{print $1,$2}' users.lst
```